# Removing Wall with 2x4 roof supports attached

Tags: walls, attic

I am working on a home remodeling project and would like to remove a wall. When investigating the structure. The wall runs parallel right between two rafters. On top of the wall there are 2 2x4's that go from the top of the wall to the roof. I was wondering if I could either remove or move these supports or do I need to install a beam to replace the wall for these supports. See Pictures. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I've made the images upright, but it's still hard to see what's going on. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the tour.  The 2x4 go from the roof ridges to the top wall header. I was just wondering if this is structural for the roof ridges and if so can I relocate to another near by wall completely remove them without causing any problems.

Comment: It's likely going to be tough for us to answer authoritatively, but let's see if one of our pros weighs in.